# How to not unpack all returned from a query?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I have the following query (notice not a normal SELECT):

```
sql = "SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db <> 'sys' "
```

Problem this returns many fields, which I need only the first two, see full code:

```
sql = "SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db <> 'sys' "
self.cursor.execute(sql)
res = [(Db,Name) for(Db,Name,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j) in self.cursor]
```

For this to not error out, I need to add all those `a...j` variables which I do nothing with.
How do I write this in a cleaner way?

I am using the connector supplied by Mysql/Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
res = [(Db,Name) for(Db,Name,*_) in self.cursor]
```

The `*` format in tuple unpacking represents "*a "catch-all" name which will be assigned a list of all items not assigned to a "regular" name.*"

References:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Comment: For some reason it works just with he underline, the * causes syntax error (I am on py3.4)

Comment: My mistake, seems the problem is in the Eclipse interpreter. When run from command line all is good.

Answer (score 2):

Don't unpack the row into multiple variables to begin with. Just put the row into one variable and take what you want from that.

```
[(row[0], row[1]) for row in self.cursor]
```

or maybe even:

```
[row[:2] for row in self.cursor]
```